# Getting a ORA-01722: invalid number even though there is no attempt to convert a varchar2 to a number

Tags: sql, oracle

The query is a bit long

```
select user_aud_view.audit_id,
user_aud_view.user_id,
(users.last_name_txt || CHR(44) || users.first_name_txt) as user_name,
user_aud_view.column_name_txt,
user_aud_view.old_value_txt,
user_aud_view.new_value_txt,
case when evaluator.country_id like '%CAN%' then to_char(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,'YYYY/MM/DD HH12:MI:SS AM')
else to_char(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM') end as    audit_last_updated_dt ,
user_aud_view.audit_updated_user_id,
evaluator.evaluator_name_txt,
evaluator.evaluator_id,
TRIM(TO_CHAR(to_evaluatortime(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,115) ,'Month'))||' '||TO_CHAR(to_evaluatortime(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,115) ,'dd'||','||' yyyy') AS DAILY_TXT,
trim(to_char(to_evaluatortime(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,115) ,'Month')) || ' ' || to_char(to_evaluatortime(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,115) ,'yyyy') AS MONTHLY_TXT,
decode(to_char(to_evaluatortime(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,115) ,'Q'),1,'January - March',2,'April - June',3,'July - September',4,'October - December') || ' ' || to_char(to_evaluatortime(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,115) ,'yyyy') AS QUARTERLY_TXT,
to_char(to_evaluatortime(user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt,115) ,'yyyy') AS YEARLY_TXT
from user_aud_view,
users,
evaluator
WHERE user_aud_view.evaluator_id = evaluator.evaluator_id
and user_aud_view.user_id = users.user_id
and user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt >= to_dbtime(to_date('07/01/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),115)  and user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt < to_dbtime(to_date('08/01/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),115)   AND ( (user_aud_view.evaluator_id = 115) )   ORDER BY user_id ASC, user_id ASC
```

It complains about the error on this line:

```
and user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt >= to_dbtime(to_date('07/01/2012', 
'mm/dd/yyyy'),115)  and user_aud_view.audit_last_updated_dt < to_dbtime(to_date('08/01/2012', 'mm/dd/yyyy'),115)   
AND ( (user_aud_view.evaluator_id = 115) )   ORDER BY user_id ASC, user_id ASC
                                                                    *
```

ERROR at line 21:
ORA-01722: invalid number

However, user_id is a VARCHAR2 field.

I am not aware of the data in those fields, because we don't have access to this client's database.

Comment: Why 2 sorts for the same field? " ORDER BY user_id ASC, user_id ASC"

Comment: Its the way jsp struts constructs the SQL, one ORDER by is added when selected by Grouping and the other one is added by default.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess that user_aud_view.evaluator_id is based on a varchar column. You might try this:

```
AND ( (user_aud_view.evaluator_id = '115') )   ORDER BY user_id ASC, user_id ASC
```

Comment: It is of type NUMBER, but I will make sure that is the case, because while generating the view, it was used as a select * from another_table, where it is a NUMBER as well.